# VB.net + WUA Change image via code

Tags: vb.net, image, win-universal-app

Im Creating a WUA (Windows universal App) in Visual Basic and Visual Studio 2015.

I have an image on screen and all I want to do is change said image when a button is clicked.

This simple process seems to have changed since VB 2010, with the use of picture boxes.

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you create a windows universal 8.1 app? Did you mean you have an Image control in the app and  you want to change the picture of that image control? What simple process you mean here?

Comment: No, I believe I created a "Bland App (Universal Windows)